# Printing nested JSON dictionary

Tags: php, json

I have an API and I have problem accessing the contents using PHP.

Below is the API structure:

```
"data": {
  "1076056102": {
    "achievements": {
        "armorPiercer": 25,
        "rare1070": 1,
        "aimer": 4,
        "invader": 12,
        ...//
```

Below is the code I have to try and access it. Any help would be nice thank you.

```
$url = '...'; JSON PATH
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put contents in variable
$stats = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
?>

<html>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Achievement</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($stats as $stat) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $stat->armorPiercer; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $stat->rare1070; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $stat->aimer; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $stat->invader; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you could include the error you are experiencing?

Comment: its quite obvious lol

Comment: It looks like you need to use `$stat->achievements->armorPiercer` and so on.

Comment: Utkanos it isn't my question! Answer below

Comment: @delboy1978uk - my bad; need coffee this early in a morning. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $object->data->{1076056102}->achievements->armorPiercer;
```

will work. However, I'm guessing you won't know those ID's specifically.

So, turn it into an associative array rather than a `stdClass` by passing true to `json_decode()`:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['data'] as $row) {
    echo $row['achievements']['armorPiercer']; // echoes 25
}
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/4W3mm

Comment: Awsome demo. I'll incorporate in code now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!